# Firefox border-radius rendering weird wide effects

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am having some eird side effects when using border-radius in firefox.
Opening the following html renders some triangles on some of the button borders.
see the side effetcs here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDc5Z.png (I do not have enough reputations for images)

the code is

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input style="border-radius: 10px;" value="Continue" type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any ideas ? I am using FF 28.0
Thanks

Comment: I think we need to see a JSfiddle with the full CSS as I suspect you have some other properties which might be affecting it.

Comment: @Paulie_D : not sure what jsfiddle is, but this is the html as is, and it shows the side effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is working all browser:

**CSS**

```
.myButton {
    width: 180px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    font: normal 11px/48px "Lucida Grande";
    border: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 67px;
    -moz-border-radius: 67px;
    border-radius: 67px;
    background-image: rgba(235,235,235,1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%,#d6d6d6 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%,#d6d6d6 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%,#d6d6d6 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%,#d6d6d6 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%,#d6d6d6 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="myButton">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure it is a browser issue. Try updating or try going through these troubleshooting steps: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-look-wrong-or-appear-differently

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is recommended to copy important parts from the link to the answer, as the link may become inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the themes/skins for Firefox can change default behavior of form elements, including buttons. That may be one of potential causes. Can be resolved with:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```